# Which program is releasing Linux's Dynamic IP address, if dhclient already killed?

Tags: dhcp

After dhclient was killed, in short term, I didn't see the Dynamic IP lost. Then, after a weekend, the Dynamic IP address is gone.

Just wonder which program released it.

Comment: Add more detail: It's not about the DHCP sever, the client released it's own ip address after some period, I'm sure it was not done by dhclient (because I removed the dhclient package). I need find out which program did it...

Comment: You should put necessary additional details in your question rather than add it as a comment.

Comment: The additional details actually obscure your question...  So, you removed the `dhclient` program and left the system running... and after some time the Dynamic IP address assigned to the interface by your DHCP server was unset... is that correct?  And then no new address lease was acquired by your interface?  Is that the problem?  If there is no DHCP client running, any set addresses will expire with no new lease.

Comment: Related: [Prevent DHCP release during shutdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152451/how-do-you-prevent-a-dhcp-release-during-shutdown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Debian system, using NetworkManager + dhclient sets a timer on the IP assigned by dhclient (with initial configuration changed by NetworkManager). This timer is directly managed by the kernel. After recently bringing up the interface, here's how it looks:

```
# ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.6.0.122/24 brd 10.6.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 7150sec preferred_lft 7150sec
```

If nothing refreshes it, the IP will be removed directly by the kernel in 7150s. Renewing the lease will refresh this value. Which is certainly related with my DHCP server's `default-lease-time 7200;` configuration.

Here's a simple example adding for only 10s an IP on the `lo` interface:

```
term1# ip -4 -o monitor addr|while read -r l; do printf '%s\n' "$l" | sed "s/^/$(date --iso-8601=s) /"; done
2018-11-19T21:10:18+00:00 1: lo    inet 10.1.1.1/32 scope global dynamic lo\       valid_lft 10sec preferred_lft 5sec
2018-11-19T21:10:23+00:00 1: lo    inet 10.1.1.1/32 scope global deprecated dynamic lo\       valid_lft 5sec preferred_lft 0sec
2018-11-19T21:10:28+00:00 Deleted 1: lo    inet 10.1.1.1/32 scope global deprecated dynamic lo\       valid_lft 0sec preferred_lft 0sec
```

when doing on term2:

```
term2# ip addr add dev lo 10.1.1.1 preferred_lft 5 valid_lft 10
term2# ip -4 -br a  show dev lo
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 10.1.1.1/32 
term2# ip -4 -br a  show dev lo
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
```

Debian stretch's dhclient doesn't handle `valid_lft` (but NetworkManager does add it). On other systems, eg CentOS, `valid_lft` is handled by dhclient, as seen in a few lines in `/sbin/dhclient-script`:

```
351     # replace = add if it doesn't exist or override (update lifetimes) if it's there
352     ip -4 addr replace ${new_ip_address}/${new_prefix} broadcast ${new_broadcast_address} dev ${interface} \
353        valid_lft ${new_dhcp_lease_time} preferred_lft ${new_dhcp_lease_time} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

So if your specific setting is having `valid_lft` set differently from `forever`, the answer should be: the kernel did it.

Comment: It seems there is no other program other than kernel did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When using DHCP, you don't "own" the IP address, you "lease" it.

As a metaphor, imagine that you lease a car. The lease is for some period of time, perhaps 12 months. After that time expires, you need to go back and sign some paperwork for a new lease if you want to be allowed to continue driving the car. If you decide to skip signing the paperwork, you don't get to keep driving the car: if your lease expires and you don't renew it, the owner of the car is allowed to take it back. If you do nothing, you don't magically get a new car. Instead you simply have no car at all.

Likewise, turning off `dhclient` doesn't let you keep the IP address. It just means you stop going back for more paperwork. So when (not if!) the IP address expires, you don't get a new one. You just get no IP address at all.